# Unable to call paginated API actix

Tags: rust, actix-web

I am writing an service that calls a paginated API with actix, I have searched docs and cannot figure out how to do this.
Can anyone please provide pointers?

Here is what I currently have:

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct Balances {
    balances: Vec<Balance>,
    #[serde(rename = "current-round")]
    current_round: i64,
    #[serde(rename = "next-token")]
    next_token: Option<String>,
}

async fn get_data() -> i64 {
    let client = reqwest::Client::new();
    let response = client
        .get(&env::var("ALGOD_URL_1").unwrap())
        .header("x-api-key", &env::var("ALGOD_TOKEN").unwrap())
        .header(CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
        .header(ACCEPT, "application/json")
        .header("pragma", "public")
        .send()
        .await
        .unwrap()
        .json::<Balances>()
        .await
        .unwrap();

    response.balances.len() as i64
}

async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    dotenv().ok();
    get_data();
}
```

Unfortunately, this only returns the first page how the results.

Comment: well...what is the API specification? My guess is that you will have to use the `next_token` to request the next page...but who knows....

Comment: I am guessing you need this https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/reqwest/struct.RequestBuilder.html#method.query